# How can I edit the data in the QUERY results to reflect the updates in the source table?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There is a situation when I want to correct some data in a sheet with the `QUERY()` results because otherwise, it is too exhausting to search for a row where the updates should be applied in the source sheet.

However, the updates are not reflected in the source sheet, so I have to anyway apply updates in the source sheet.

Comment: You can't. You need AppScript to alter source data.

Comment: I suggest you look into Filter Views, they'll allow you to do something similar than QUERY with the filters and sorting options and you'll be able to work with the source data directly

Comment: It would be great if you share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried already.